# Difference between Contains vs ST_Contains Mysql

Tags: mysql

What is the difference between `Contains` vs `ST_Contains` and which one to use?

```
Contains(region_data," +"GeomFromText('Point(" + latitude + " " + longitude + ")'))
```

vs

```
ST_Contains(region_data," +"GeomFromText('Point(" + latitude + " " + longitude + ")'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ST_Contains(g1, g2)
```

Returns 1 or 0 to indicate whether g1 completely contains g2. This tests the opposite relationship as ST_Within().

```
contains(g1, g2)  uses MBR only (not exact!)
st_contains(g1, g2) uses exact shapes
```

I think this link will help you a lot [MySQL Spatial Functions for Geo-Enabled Applications](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-mysql-spatial-functions-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/)